# How to inject background image url into styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components as a design library, I created a div that will hold a background image with its properties, if I inject the image url from outside the styled components it doesnt take and and does some mistakes.

Ill copy some code:

image-div component as styled component:

```
const ImageDiv = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: cover;

`
export default ImageDiv;
```

using the ImageDiv on a screen and passing it a background image doesnt take the background properties from above

```
<ImageDiv style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${signin})` }} src = {signin} alt="logo" />
```

I will like to be able to pass the url as a prop and inject it into the styled component from above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply pass it as another prop, then use it inside styled component as `background-image` property.

```
<ImageDiv bg={signin} src={signin} alt="logo" />

const ImageDiv = styled.div`
   background-image: url(${(props) => props.bg});   
`;
```

Comment: I think the syntax for this  url(${(props) => props.bg});  is wrong

Comment: @SImonHaddad Why do you think so? Do you get some errors? Syntax is fine

Comment: No errors , but it doesnt show me any images anymore, and url is the correct one

Comment: @SImonHaddad same for me, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring props

```
const ImageDiv = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: ${({url}) => `url(${url})`};
`
export default ImageDiv;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attrs` manipulator to change the attributes directly on the generated component. Through this, you can change several things, like buttons disabled-attribute or href for anchor tags, for example!

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { prop } from 'styled-tools'

export const ImageDiv = styled.div.attrs(({ url }: { url: string })`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: ${prop('url')};
`
```